# Error trying to install lxml (following Hitchhiker's guide to Python)

Tags: python, lxml

**Error trying to install lxml (following Hitchhiker's guide to Python -- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/#lxml-and-requests)**

Here is the error log:

http://pastebin.com/p37CRUKV

What should I do?

I tried pip install libxslt & pip install libxml2 but I got errors from both of these: libxslt -- http://pastebin.com/ZJhvgHhd; libxml2 -- http://pastebin.com/eyE2Wbg2#

I also tried using easy_install lxml but it failed too.

Comment: `** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **` -- have you installed them?

Comment: Hi Lambda, I added the error logs from trying to pip install those to my post. I'm following scanny's advice though anyway and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're on Windows. You'll almost certainly want to install from a binary installer. Back in a second with the link ...

Here you go:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

`lxml` is a Python binding on the libxml2 and libxslt C libraries. As a result, the install involves a compile step, AND you need to have those two libraries installed. As a (big) convenience, the binary installer is provided that has all that bit done for you. Big job otherwise, involving having Visual Studio C compiler installed and other bits that are pretty hairy if you don't have occasion to do that sort of thing much :)